# Get relative coordinates of other agents

Tags: netlogo

What's the best way to get coordinates of one agent relative to the coordinates of another agent in such a way that respects world wrapping?

That is, the naive solution is:

```
to-report relative-xcor [ other-agent ]
  report [ xcor ] of other-agent - xcor
end
```

(and similar for `ycor`) The problem with that code is that it will be wrong when, for instance, the main agent is on the far right side of the screen and `other-agent` is on the far left.

Ideas? My best idea so far is to use `towards` and trigonometry, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Edit:

To give an example of why the above is wrong, suppose your world has `min-pxcor = -5` and `max-pxcor = 5`, and has wrapping on. If we have `turtle 0` at `xcor = 5` and `turtle 1` at `xcor = -5`, then `[ relative-xcor turtle 1 ] of turtle 0` would give `-10` whereas the correct answer is `1` (due to world wrapping). I suppose implicit in my question is that it should give the smallest (by absolute value) relative coordinate.

Comment: Could you give us some examples using a 1D world? My issue is that I don't understand why your function is incorrect---it *does* provide relative coordinates. I think you want to get the minimal magnitude:   let d1 [ xcor ] of other-agent - xcor let d2 world-width - xcor + [xcor] of other-agent  ifelse (abs d1) < (abs d2) [report d1] [report d2]

Answer (score 1):

(OP here) So the only solution I've come up with so far is:

```
to-report rel-xcor [ other-agent ]
  report ifelse-value (self = other-agent) [
    0
  ] [
    0 - (sin towards other-agent) * distance other-agent
  ]
end

to-report rel-ycor [ other-agent ]
  report ifelse-value (self = other-agent) [
    0
  ] [
    0 - (cos towards other-agent) * distance other-agent
  ]
end
```

(recall that since netlogo angles are flipped, `cos` gives y coordinate and `sin` gives x)

But that seems overly complicated. But if anyone stumbles on this question wondering the same thing, this is what I'm currently using. I'll happily accept a better answer though.